# colocando a opção de desistir no jogo de adivinhar números Python

Tags: python

Estou iniciando no mundo do Pyhton
e me desafiando tentando criar esse jogo de adivinhar o numero

```
import random

lista = random.randint(1, 100)
numero = lista

print('''olá voce esta aqui para tentar acertar o numero que eu selecionei
vamos começar?''')
print('o numero esta entre 1 e 100')
chute1 = int(input('''chute um numero!
'''))
print('=-' * 30)

while chute1 != numero:
    if chute1 >= numero:
        print('chute alto!')
        chute1 = int(input('''chute um numero
'''))
        print('=-' * 30)
    elif chute1 <= numero:
        print('chute baixo!')
        chute1 = int(input('''chute um numero
'''))
        print('=-' * 30)

else:
    print('Voce acertou parabens!')

print()
```

porem toda vez que eu vou colocar um resposta para o jogador desistir da erro,
eu tento colocar dessa forma:

```
    elif chute1 == 'desisti':
        print('Voce desistiu')
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá na opção desistir?

Comment: "" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC-Rodrigo\Desktop\ExerciciosPy\MeusDesafios\AcerteNumero.py", line 19, in <module>
    chute1 = int(input('''chute um numero
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'desisto' ""

Comment: Ao fazer `int(input(...))`, o que for digitado é convertido para número. Se vc digitar "desistir" (ou qualquer outra palavra), esse texto não pode ser convertido para número, daí o erro. Além disso, a lógica está errada, pois vc usou `>=` (ou seja, se o número for igual, entraria no primeiro `if` - só não entra por causa do `while`, mas não precisa complicar tanto). Enfim, um jeito de fazer é só converter para número depois de verificar se o usuário desistiu: https://ideone.com/0j4wNa

Answer (score -2):

Reformulando então segundo o teu comentário à resposta e aplicando com exemplos o que tinha dito anteriormente.

Primeiramente tu n podes comparar uma string com um numero inteiro sendo assim irei usar o 0 para sair do programa uma vez que o torna mais facil.

**Esta parte acho que é o mais importante para ti e se o poderes aplicar vai ser incrível**

Tenta deixar o teu código mais limpo para que seja mais fácil tanto tu como os outros o entenderes e resolveres possíveis erros que apareçam, o código que deixaste torna bastante dificil fazê-lo.

*Código Exemplo abaixo*

```
import random

#Atribui um numero random
lista = random.randint(1, 100)
numero = lista

#Inicializa chute1
chute1 = None

while chute1 != numero:
    # Pede ao user um numero
    chute1 = int(input('chute um numero: '))

    #opcao de desistir
    if chute1 == 0:
        break
    
    if chute1!=numero:
        #compara o numero introduzido com o random
        if chute1 < numero:
            print("Chute mais alto")
        else:
            print("Chute mais baixo")
```

Repara que consegues orientar-te muito melhor ao seguir um codigo mais limpo e explicito, espero ter ajudado e espero que isto te ajude a compreender o erro e o pq de n funcionar.

Só para deixar uma outra resposta uma vez que pareceu que estavas realmente a usar a string "desistir" para desistir e para que consigas tmb compreender melhor como poderia ser feito.

```
import random

#Atribui um numero random
lista = random.randint(1, 100)
numero = lista

#Inicializa chute1
chuteFinal = None

while chuteFinal != numero:
    # Pede ao user um numero
    chute1 = input('chute um numero: ')

    #opcao de desistir
    if chute1 == 'desistir':
        break

    chuteFinal = int(chute1)

    if chuteFinal != numero:
        #compara o numero introduzido com o random
        if chuteFinal < numero:
            print("Chute mais alto")
        else:
            print("Chute mais baixo")
```

Neste caso o que eu fiz foi, pedir ao usuario para introduzir a resposta em string e verificar se ele queria desistir, só depois converter para um numero inteiro e fazer as comparaçoes.

Comment: sobre a parte de introduzir um numero inteiro, eu ja troquei e tirei porem mesmo assim nao funciona, quando eu tiro o "int" acaba mostrando um erro dizendo que "==, >=, <=" nao sao compativeis com o codigo em geral

Comment: Modifiquei a minha resposta de acordo com o teu comentário

Comment: muito obrigado, entao pelo que eu entendi nao teria como eu colocar "Desistir" ao inves do "0" certo? Como forma de resposta do user

Comment: Tem sim, daria para fazer isso tranquilamente basta criares um input de string em vez de um input de inteiro e antes de fazeres as comparaçoes(while/if) converteres a string para um inteiro eu fiz desta maneira pois é, na minha opiniao, a maneira mais eficiente de o fazer

Comment: Outra maneira de o fazer tambem seria manter o codigo atual com os inputs de numeros inteiros e criar um novo input de string para desistir. O que não podes fazer é colocar um input de inteiros e esperar que nao dê erro quando é comparado com uma string